# Timing of Task Result Evaluation

Tags: .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0

This is an "academic" question as opposed to one affecting anything I am currently working on in an official capacity, but I figure somebody here can explain this to me.

I'm playing around with `CancellationToken` in [LinqPAD](http://www.linqpad.net/) (I mention this detail so people unfamiliar with it know that `Dump()` is basically short-hand for `Console.WriteLine()`) and I was trying out a scenario where I have the main thread sleep while my task completes. This was done after running several variations of cancelling the task before it could complete to play with the `IsCanceled` property and verify that the `Result` property is not accessible when cancelled. Here's what my dummy LinqPAD program looks like:

```
void Main()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Test())
                            .ContinueWith(t => t.Result, cts.Token)
                            .ContinueWith(t => 
                            { 
                                if (t.IsCanceled)
                                {
                                    "Cancelled".Dump();
                                }
                                else if (t.IsCompleted)
                                {
                                    "Completed".Dump();
                                    t.Result.Sum (r => r).Dump();
                                }
                            }); 
    //sleep long enough to make sure the Task completes
    Thread.Sleep(6000);
}

private IEnumerable<int> Test()
{
    foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
    {
        yield return i;
        Task.Delay(500).Wait();
    }
}
```

This behaves--mostly--how I would expect: the output was "Completed" followed by "45". What I did not expect was that the "45" was not output until the Thread.Sleep() call finished, but "Completed" was output instantly.

So my question is: how can the `IsCompleted` flag of my task be evaluated immediately, but the `Result` property not be evaluated until after the calling thread returns from a `Thread.Sleep()` call? Additionally, is there any way I could restructure this to have either both be output immediately or both wait for the end of the `Sleep()` call?

I know this example is contrived, but I can't wrap my head around this contrived behavior.
**EDIT**
Additional question: doesn't this observed behavior imply that I could get in a state where the task's `Result` property changes between when `IsCompleted` is evaluated and when I am able to evaluate `Result`?
**EDIT 2**
After further investigation, I was able to answer one of my own questions: I can force the "Completed" output to wait until after the `Thread.Sleep()` completes by changing the behavior of `Test()` to return an IList<> that is built-up in the method instead of `yield return`ing an IEnumerable. I understand how IEnumerable works generally, but the behavior I'm seeing here by introducing tasks is what is throwing me off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because of the way 'yield return' and IEnumerable<> works.

So when you call Test() it doesn't actually running the loop, it just returns an IEnumerable<>.

To prove you can run this code -

```
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var results = Test();


    Console.WriteLine("Time after running Test {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Looping {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

So only after this line of code-
t.Result.Sum (r => r).Dump();
You start looping and waiting on the Task.Delay(500).Wait();
When finished will sum up the numbers and write it to the console.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm accessing the IEnumerable in a different Task (via the `ContinueWith` construct), so why should that be affected by a `Sleep` in my main thread?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What effect are you talking about in the Main thread? There are 2 threads. 1 - The Main, 2 - The created task.

Comment: the effect I am talking about is why the `Sum()` doesn't execute until the `Thread.Sleep()` completes.

Comment: Ahh, I completely forgot about the `Task.Delay()` I left in the `Test()` method! That explains it perfectly. Sorry for the runaround due to my lack of reading comprehension.